# If div contains certain word, replace entire sentence it's in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, contains

I'm looking for a way to search a div for a certain word within a sentence and if found then replace the entire sentence with something else.

So, for example, if the div contains a title of "My Dad cooks the best apple pie", then I want to find the word "apple" and then replace the ENTIRE sentence with something else, for example: "My Dad".

I found this, but that only replaces the actual word in the sentence, whereas I want to replace the entire sentence.

```
$(".div_class").text(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace("word", "another word"); 
});​​​​​
```

Greatly appreciate any help, as always.

Comment: Have a look at the `:contains` selector - http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/HdhuH/?

Comment: try this `$(".div_class").text(function(i,oldText) { return oldText.indexOf("word") != -1 ? "another word" : oldText;
});​​​​​`

Comment: @Jerpl you want to replace the sentence, not all the div content, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `:contains`

```
$( "div:contains('Apple')").text("My dad");
```

Comment: That works just fine (so simple when you know how!) but what if I want to target a div with a certain class?

Comment: `$('.your_class:contains("apple")').html('My Dad')` - http://jsfiddle.net/HdhuH/1/

Comment: Any way of putting several words to search for into one command?

Comment: @Jerpl use like this $( "div:contains('Apple'),div:contains('Dad')")